# Spring MVC: How autowiring of HttpSession works?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, autowired, httpsession

I would like to know how autowiring of HttpSession works.

If we declare like below:

```
@Autowired 
private HttpSession httpSession;
```

When exactly in the Spring workflow, httpSession variable declared above will be initialized with `request.getSession(true)`?

Comment: Not sure, why people vote down a question without understanding??

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you want to autowire HttpSession but here is how autowiring works.

To Autowire a class you need to specify it as a bean either by using annotations (@Controller, @Service, @Repository, @Component) or by declaring @Bean in config class. Once you define a bean Spring autowires or constructs the objects when the spring context initializes (during server startup for webapp and you explicitly initialize spring context in case console/standalone app).

**Since HttpSession can only be fetched from HttpServletRequest object, you cannot initialize it during application startup because there is no HttpServletRequest during startup.** If you want some logic to implement before fetching the HttpSession you can create a util method like this

```
public getHttpSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // put your logic here and return session object 
}
```

Comment: Autoriwing HttpSession is the most convenient way to access session from different classes. If Autowiring httpsession has issues many posts including this one, stackoverflow.com/questions/29487885,  will become invalid

Comment: It would be convenient if it's feasible. I have explained the reason why its not feasible in bold. Let us know if you figure out a way to autowire HttpSession which works.