# @Autowired HttpSession not saving simple String - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, httpsession

I've got a simple SpringBoot RestController:

```
@RestController
public class PasswordController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";
    public static final String IS_USER_LOGGED_IN = "isUserLoggedIn";
    public static final String BAD_REQUEST_MESSAGE = "Bad Request ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯";

    @Autowired
    private PasswordService passwordService;

    @Autowired
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/create/{name}/{password}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createNewUserAndPassword(@PathVariable final String name, @PathVariable final String password) {
        try {
            return passwordService.createNewUserAndPassword(name, password);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return ERROR_PATH;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "user/login/{name}/{password}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginUser(@PathVariable final String name, @PathVariable final String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
//        return passwordService.loginUser(name, password);
        final String result = passwordService.loginUser(name, password);
        if (result.contains(PasswordService.WELCOME_MESSAGE)) {
            this.httpSession.setAttribute("name", name);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String error() {
        return BAD_REQUEST_MESSAGE;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "getEnemies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEnemies() {
        if (this.httpSession.getAttribute("name") != null) {
            return "enemies List....";
        } else {
            return "(ง'̀-'́)ง";
        }
    }
}
```

It is quite simple as you can see, but the String I am saving here:

```
this.httpSession.setAttribute("name", name)
```

Can **never** be retrieved here as long as it is always null:

```
this.httpSession.getAttribute("name") != null
```

I debugged the code, and you can retrieve the string inmediately afterwards of the `set`. However, when it reaches the other method, it won't work at `HttpSession` object changes. (It even has another ID)

What can be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Don't `@Autowire` the `HttpSession` just add it as a method argument instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming other handler(getEnemies()) when you meant other method

Yes the object changes since they both are different rest calls which run on different threads. I'm not sure what could be the root of HttpSession object which you have injected but what ever you are storing in it might not be persistent( probably local to that Thread). That is what making you to get null value in the other method.

Comment: Yes, but, how can I prevent it to happen? I would like to retrieve that string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151804/spring-mvc-when-autowired-httpsession-will-be-created this might help you. I'm just a beginner so sorry if I couldn't get you right solution

Comment: and you have made it a restcontroller but still you are sending a string(assuming it as view) .What is your intention?